# How to serialize null value response in retrofit?

Tags: retrofit2, android, gson

GsonConverter parses in case of datas available but when null values occurs it doesn't parse data.

Here is json response

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "name": "abc store",
        "services": [
            [
                "Travel Clinic",
                "Growler Fill",
                "Fresh Food"
            ]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "abc store",
        "services": [
            [
                "Travel Clinic",
                "Coffee Bar",
                "Growler Fill",
                "Fresh Food",
                "Scoop Ice Cream"
            ]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "abc store",
        "services": [
            ""
        ]
    }]
}
```

Here is the model
Model.java

```
  { 
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("services")
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> storeServices;

  }
```

I have used these dependencies:

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0
```

Comment: your `JSON` is not valid .......

Comment: it's my bad. I have changed into valid response. Can you look again?

Comment: have look on the answer

Comment: what is the error  ??

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Comment: will you please post your Interface and retrofit call ??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in your retrofit model. Can you show it?

or try this one

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("services")
@Expose
public List<List<String>> services = null;

}
```

Comment: The model of 
{
 "services": [
        ""
      ]
}

Comment: {
 "services": [
        ""
      ]
}
is 
public List<String> services = null;

Comment: Try to edit you 2nd json to
{
 "services": [
        [""]
      ]
}

Comment: how can we handle this response "services": [
        [
          "ABC",
          "EFG",
          "ABC"
        ]
      ]

Comment: My model is suitable for "services": [ [ "ABC", "EFG", "ABC" ] ].  I suppose the problem is that your 2nd json does not suit your model. try to add a squared brackets - { "services": [ [""] ] }. Or change your model to a ArrayList<String> storeServices;

Comment: i have provided json reponse. Can you look again?

Comment: Your model expects another server response

Comment: By the way, you can get google.com.JsonObject instead of your model if you don't want to care about your model